# ImageButton in group row of ExpandableListView causing onClickListener not to be fired

Tags: android, imagebutton, expandablelistview

I am working with an ExpandableListView in my application. It worked fine until I decided to add an ImageButton to the end of it. Here is my XML:

This is my group row:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:weightSum="1">
<TextView 
    android:text="location"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_width="250dp" style="@style/listResultsTitle"
    android:id="@+id/results_location_row" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp">
</TextView>
<TextView 
    android:text="ad" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
    android:layout_height="30dp" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    style="@style/listResults" 
    android:id="@+id/results_ad_row" 
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/results_location_row" 
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/results_location_row" 
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/results_location_row">
</TextView>
<ImageButton 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/prox_order" 
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_add" 
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
</ImageButton>
```

Now, the ExpandableListView will not expand. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

EDIT: Okay, I understand what the problem is. I have a view that is focusable that causes the onItemClickListener not to be called when I click on a row. I implemented an onClickListener that captures the click, but I do not know how to expand the row. Can anyone help out? Here is the code that I have inside of my custom Adapter:

```
 v.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(groupPosition, this))
 private class OnItemClickListener implements OnClickListener{
    private int pos;
    MySimpleExpandableListAdapter adapter;
    OnItemClickListener(int groupPosition, MySimpleExpandableListAdapter _adapter){
        pos = groupPosition;
        adapter = _adapter;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.e("Adapter", "Row clicked: #" + String.valueOf(pos));
    }
}
```

~Nemisis7654

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081927/imagebutton-on-expandablelistview-child-item.

Comment: I have seen that and it didn't solve my problem. I have the image showing up where I want it to. The thing is, now that the image is there, it does not seem to be registering a click on the list so the list does not expand and I cannot see the child rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Romain Guy himself has answered your question rather succinctly in this [group discussion](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg11390.html).

Comment: Thanks. That definitely helped me figure out WHAT the problem is. Now on to solving it...

Comment: Okay, I edited my question. Do you think you could help out with it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with ExpandableListViews.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks anyway. You helped me figure out the cause of the problem. Much appreciated.